# C# Reflection - Get Property of an Object

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

I'm trying to set a property of an object in a class, but I can't get the property.

```
FieldInfo dControl = window.GetType().GetField("dControl", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
if (dControl == null) { Debug.Log ("dControl is null"); return;}

PropertyInfo inPreviewMode = dControl.GetType().GetProperty("InPreviewMode", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
if (inPreviewMode == null) { Debug.Log ("dControl.InPreviewMode is null"); return;}

inPreviewMode.SetValue(dControl, false, null);
```

*inPreviewMode* returns null, however.

This is the property I'm trying to access:

```
public class DControl : TimeArea
{
    public bool InPreviewMode
    {
        get
        {
            return dState.IsInPreviewMode;
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The class is stored as a dll if that matters.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Well you're currently trying to *set* the value (you're calling `SetValue`) and you haven't shown a setter... it would really help if you'd show a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dControl.GetType()` returns the type for `System.Reflection.FieldInfo`, since that's what `dControl` is.

You want `GetFieldType()`.

Similarly, you need an instance to pass to `SetValue()`.